# Why does Chrome log in Gmail automatically?

Tags: gmail

When opening Chrome browser, and whenever loading a page, it will show my Gmail address at the upper right corner of the web page, does that mean the Gmail is logged in automatically?

Comment: Isn't this more about Chrome, and should thus be on [su]?

Answer (score 3):

No. It means your Chrome data is being synced to the Google Account as given by the email.

Comment: so you mean that even if my a/c is logged out, this will always appear there? I am still a bit worried, so is there function of chrome to be opened and together with gmail a/c auto signed in?

Comment: @frog If you select "Disconnect your Google account" from `chrome://settings/` then it won't be shown. It's nowhere related to Gmail auto sign-in

Comment: as I understand my steps to sync my chrome to gmail require me to sign in then it can sync, so if my gmail isn't signed in, how can the chrome browser sync with my gmail?

Comment: Chrome doesn't sync to Gmail, it syncs to your Google account, which is registered to your gmail email id. You're signing in & syncing with the Google account, not Gmail.

Comment: so you mean once i got a gmail account, i will get a default and same id for google? Also i realize, in the process of sync, i have to siged in the chrome/settings/sign in first and then enter my gmail id and pw and set my sync. There is no place requiring me to sign out of the account afterwards, so it means my google account is always signed in then?

Comment: yeah, that's correct.

Comment: Pls check this link, it's the steps of doing sync, http://www.chromeplugins.org/chrome/sync-chrome-with-gmail/    and in it says clearly i have to sign in my gmail when i set the sync, does that not mean i sign in and stay in gmail account after i've done teh sync setting?

Comment: Again, to repeat. Just because the email address is a gmail, doesn't mean you're logged into gmail. You used gmail address to sign up for a service, and when you login with that account, you're signing into that service, not into Gmail. same concept holds here.

Comment: do you mean that when i am signing up a service by logging in that gmail a/c, this step doesn't auto sign me in with my gmail account, so there is no need for me to do the 'sign out' in order to back out the email?